# MySQL query WHERE IN for json array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, where-in

I have saved data for a column in json form:

```
{"sp_id": [1, 2,113],"spd_id": [],"spclg_id": []}
```

I would like to use WHERE IN to check if the `sp_id` field contains the values ​​specified in the array

i.e. I want to check whether there is at least one occurrence of the given values ​​in the `u_id` array.

- At least one element for `sp_id` must match
- must be in mysql
- mysql version:  5.7.40

in php it would look like this:

```
if(count(array_intersect($needle, $haystack)))
```

Comment: There is no `u_id` in your JSON, which makes your question rather unclear.

Comment: corrected, sorry :)

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: You want to do this directly in mysql using `where` clause? and all items must match e.g. `[1, 2, 113]` -> match, `[1, 2]` -> no match?

Comment: @SalmanA at least one element must match, must be in mysql, cannot be in a loop in php

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @SalmanA  5.7.40

Comment: Think you are looking for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains

Comment: @user3783243 checks if there is only one value for a field, I need to check if there is at least one value from the given ones

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you store these data in JSON? It would have been easy to query if you had stored multi-valued attributes as normal rows and columns.

Comment: @ninka436 That's the same thing, no? If you have 1 value than you have at least 1 value.... or you have `$haystack` which is an array of ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON_CONTAINS` function which, unfortunately, has some limitations. You need to check items one by one:

```
-- e.g. when you need to check if [1, 9] intersects

WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('{"sp_id": [1, 2, 113], "spd_id": [], "spclg_id": []}', '1', '$.sp_id') -- true
OR    JSON_CONTAINS('{"sp_id": [1, 2, 113], "spd_id": [], "spclg_id": []}', '9', '$.sp_id') -- false
```

The better solution is to use `JSON_TABLE` which requires MySQL 8 or later:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM JSON_TABLE(t.json, '$.sp_id[*]' COLUMNS(
        val INT PATH '$'
    )) AS x
    WHERE val IN (1, 9)
)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UMj681OO)

Comment: only I can have a lot of these values, that's why I wanted to avoid using JSON_CONTAINS... And what would the use of OPENJSON look like? I can't find this function in the documentation, this function is available for mysql?

Comment: Sorry it was JSON_TABLE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html, but your hands are tied. `JSON_SEARCH` can do exact match of `[1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 113]` but not `[1, 9]`.

Comment: We are currently planning to upgrade the company

Comment: You will show me what ```JSON_TABLE```  will look like in my case?

Comment: @ninka436: Note that `JSON_TABLE()` is not implemented in MySQL 5.7. You said you're currently using MySQL 5.7, so you would have to upgrade. But MySQL 5.7 will reach end of support in October of this year, so you should probably be planning to upgrade anyway.

Comment: thank you very much, now I only have a performance problem, jsons don't work for INDEX, won't such a query kill the database?

Comment: I'd rather not store the data as json if it is used in where clause.